# Understanding Dask-ML

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have read through Dask-ML documentation and I have googled around, but have 2 questions I would like some clarity on if anyone could assists:

- by saying "using a cluster of computers", does it mean processing is distributed across other people's computers who are connected to the network? If yes, would there be any privacy issues with this?
- would we be able to know how many computers are there in a cluster at any point in time?

Please point me to the right direction or if there are any link that I could read more about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for general documentation on Dask

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest

And in particular on how to set up Dask on a set of machines

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup.html